# Show that limit of integrals of sequence of orthonormal functions in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ goes to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\psi_n$, $n=1,2,...$ be a sequence of functions in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ such that $\int_0^{2\pi}\psi_n(t)\psi_m(t)dt$ is equal to $1$ for $n=m$ and vanishes for $n \neq m$. If $A \subset [0,2\pi]$ and $A$ is measurable, prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_A \psi_n(x)dx = 0.$$

I'm sorry for my lack of an attempt here, I do normally try to post as much work as I have done, but I honestly have no idea where to start with this one. If someone would give me a hint, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: A good place to start is Bessel's Inequality: $\sum_n\big|\langle\psi_n,\psi\rangle\big|^2\le\|\psi\|^2_2$ for each $\psi\in L^2([0,2\pi])$. Use this with $\psi =1_A$.

Comment: Bessel's inequality implies that only finitely many of the terms $\langle \psi_n,\psi \rangle$ can be non-zero, which would imply that this limit is $0$... correct? Man, I can't believe I didn't see that, it is so simple!

Comment: @poppy3345: It does **not** imply that only finitely many coefficients are zero. But it does imply that the series $\sum_n |\langle \psi_n, \psi \rangle |^2$ is convergent. In particular, the sequence of summands forms a null-sequence.